# How to combine two text files using bash

Tags: bash

I have two text files that I wish to combine in bash so that every line in one file is combined with every file in the other file.

file1.txt

```
abc123
def346
ghj098
```

file2.txt

```
PSYC1001
PSYC1002
PSYC1003
```

I want to combine them so that line 1 of `file1` is added to every line of `file2`, with a pipe de-limiter `|` in between them.

e.g.

```
PSYC1001|abc123
PSYC1002|abc123
PSYC1003|abc123
```

Then the same for the other lines in file1 so I would end up with

```
PSYC1001|abc123
PSYC1002|abc123
PSYC1003|abc123
PSYC1001|def346
PSYC1002|def346
PSYC1003|def346
PSYC1001|ghj098
PSYC1002|ghj098
PSYC1003|ghj098<
```

I've been doing similar simpler text things in `bash` by copying examples from this site, but I've not found an example that can do this.  Would love to hear your suggestion.  I know it must be simple but I've not worked it out yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortest one - **`join`** command:

```
join -j2 -t'|' -o2.1,1.1 file1 file2
```

- `-t'|'` - input/output field separator
- `-o FORMAT` - `FORMAT` is one or more comma or blank separated specifications, each being `FILENUM.FIELD` or `0`

---

The output:

```
PSYC1001|abc123
PSYC1002|abc123
PSYC1003|abc123
PSYC1001|def346
PSYC1002|def346
PSYC1003|def346
PSYC1001|ghj098
PSYC1002|ghj098
PSYC1003|ghj098
```

Answer (score 4):

This awk one-liner should help you:

```
awk -v OFS="|" 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;c=NR;next}{for(i=1;i<=c;i++){print a[i],$0}}' file2 file1
```

Test with your data:

```
kent$  awk -v OFS="|" 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;c=NR;next}{for(i=1;i<=c;i++){print a[i],$0}}' f2 f1
PSYC1001|abc123
PSYC1002|abc123
PSYC1003|abc123
PSYC1001|def346
PSYC1002|def346
PSYC1003|def346
PSYC1001|ghj098
PSYC1002|ghj098
PSYC1003|ghj098
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are 2 ways to do it in plain bash:

```
while IFS= read -u3 -r elem1; do 
    while IFS= read -u4 -r elem2; do 
        echo "$elem2|$elem1"
    done 4<file2.txt
done 3<file1.txt
```

```
mapfile -t f1 < file1.txt
mapfile -t f2 < file2.txt
for elem1 in "${f1[@]}"; do 
    for elem2 in "${f2[@]}"; do 
        echo "$elem2|$elem1"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

**bash only**

```
a1=( $(<f1) )
a2=( $(<f2) )

for i in "${a2[@]}"
do
 for j in "${a1[@]}"
  do
   echo "${j}|${i}"
 done
done
```

Comment: Worth a suggestion pal.. Glen's solution has already portrayed how to do it..The op should do it in similar lines..

Comment: the main difficulty here is if the input files contain spaces or wildcards that match the user's files: `a=( $(cat file) )` is as bad as `for line in $(cat file)` in that it does not store/iterate *lines* but *words*